# SQL - Loop in a Procedure

Tags: sql, loops, procedure

I have made the following two procedures. One getting data from a view and the other is meant to make a loop. For some reason the procedures are not working properly. After 3 hours I cancelled the procedure.
The view itself gets data within a minute.

Does any of you have any idea what is going wrong?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetShipData
    @shipCode NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN 
   
    WITH voyages AS
    (
        SELECT [vslCode], [voyNum], ... -- andere kolommen
        FROM [IceBerg].[MRV].[voyage_copy]
        WHERE vslCode = @shipCode
    ),
    schedule AS (
        SELECT ...
        FROM [IceBerg].[mrv].[vsched_copy] AS vc
        LEFT JOIN voyages ON voyages.vslCode = vc.ves_code
        WHERE vc.ves_code = @shipCode -- of wellicht 'vesselcode' afhankelijk van uw schema
    ),
    -- Other CTEs or subqueries
   
    -- Final Select

    SELECT * FROM ...
    -- Every vslcode in the query has been replaced by @shipcode
END
```

And I made another procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PopulateNewEventsLogistic
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @vslCodes TABLE (vslCode NVARCHAR(50));
    INSERT INTO @vslCodes (vslCode) VALUES ('V018'), ('V019'), ('V020'); -- Voeg hier de gewenste vslCodes toe

    DECLARE @currentVslCode NVARCHAR(50);

    WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @vslCodes) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @currentVslCode = vslCode FROM @vslCodes;

        -- Execute GetShipData for current vslcode
        INSERT INTO MRV.new_events_logistic
        EXEC GetShipData @currentVslCode;

        DELETE FROM @vslCodes WHERE vslCode = @currentVslCode;
    END
END;
```

The view is a complex view with 20 steps. However it takes only a minute to get the results of the view for a vslcode. It takes however 3 hours for the procedures and it is still not finished then.

Perhaps you guys can enlighten me what is going wrong.

I tried writing the procedures but it didn't help

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: I don't really understand what this is supposed to achieve, but you almost certainly don't need a loop. How about sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Can you execute this procedure in your DBMS? If so try adding debug steps with **PRINT()** to see were the program gets stuck. You could also use **GETDATE()** before and after calling a procedure and print the **DATEDIFF()** to see how long each step inside the loop takes.

I can't see anything inherently wrong with the code that would make it get stuck in a loop.